# Laravel migration error in connection

Tags: php, laravel

I try to work on new laravel project and I get error below on `php artisan migrate`

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th
  e right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL: create table `addresses` () default character set utf8mb4 c
  ollate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


In Connection.php line 452:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th
  e right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

What I did so far:

I added codes below to my `AppServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/////
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

And changed this part of my `database.php`

```
'strict' => true,
```

TO

```
'strict' => false,
```

And still get the same error.

As it is mentioned in my error code, this is related to my `addresses` table. Here it is:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('postalcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('province');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Also my `env` file connection is like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Any idea?

Comment: you would like to `create` the table twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the second instance you should use Schema::table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('postalcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('province');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```